# Unity | Setting audio mixer values works inside a foreach loop but not outside of one

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This isn't really a question that desperately needs an answer, just a bit of confusion on my part.

I was creating an audio system for my game where the user can change the volume via sliders. I store the value of the slider inside a `PlayerPref` and convert the value into logarithmic form to apply to the audio mixer for a smoother transition. But that not really relevant to the question, just a bit of context.

On start up I tried using this code to set the volume of the audio mixer groups to the level that the user has assigned:

```
// Called in Start()
void SetValues ()
{
    // Set the relevant audio volume
    mixer.SetFloat("musicVolume", Mathf.Log10(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("musicVolume", 0.5f) * 20));
    mixer.SetFloat("soundFxVolume", Mathf.Log10(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("soundFxVolume", 0.5f) * 20));
}
```

However, this wasn't working. The volume was always its default value when opening up the game.

I tried a couple of things to no avail, and then for no particular reason tried this:

```
// Called in Start()
void SetValues ()
{
    // Set the relevant audio volume
    string[] exposedParams = { "musicVolume", "soundFxVolume" };
    foreach (var item in exposedParams) mixer.GetFloat(item, Mathf.Log10(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat(item), 0.5f) * 20);
}
```

And that worked. The correct volume levels were being assigned to the audio mixer.

Does anyone have any idea why? I can't make any sense of this.

Comment: Note that in the loop your calculation is `Mathf.Log10(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat(item)) * 20` so you multiply the **result** of log10 by `20` ... outside of the loop you are multiplying the value you **pass to** log10 `Mathf.Log10(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("musicVolume") * 20)` ... I would assume this was a typo?

Comment: Also note that `// Set the default volume values` is actually wrong ... you are using `PlayerPrefs.GetFloat` which **returns** a `float` or the deafult value `0.5f` if the according key wasn't found in the PlayerPrefs. You do nowhere store these returned values so your call is absolutely useless ;)

Comment: @derHugo In regard to the calculation, yes I think that was a typo. As for the `PlayerPrefs`, I seemed to have misunderstood how they actually work. Would the correct code look something like, for example, `mixer.SetFloat("musicVolume", Mathf.Log10(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("musicVolume", defaultValue) * 20));`. Thanks as always.